# Can you randomly assign True or False to a set of variables through multiple assignment?

Tags: python

I would like to assign either `True` or `False` to the first variable and then have a second variable assignment be the opposite of the first one. If the first variable is assigned a value of `False`, then the second variable should become `True`, and vice versa. My first thought was to do this with an if/else-statement, but it became apparent that there were too many assignments:

**Example 1:**

```
import random

if random.choice([True, False]):
  player_turn = True
  computer_turn = False
else:
  player_turn = False
  computer_turn = True


print(player_turn)
print(computer_turn)
```

I then decided to simplify the logic by leveraging the information from the first variable assignment:

**Example 2:**

```
import random

player_turn = random.choice([True, False])
computer_turn = not player_turn

print(player_turn)
print(computer_turn)
```

*Is it possible to reduce this down even further? Perhaps, by utilizing multiple assignment to have this be just one line of code?*

Comment: Do you actually need the two variables?, if you want to reduce it more you can keep just one variable and automatically you know what is the other value without needing to save it to another variable

Comment: Good question! I guess that I don't really need both variables. Although, it's more of a stylistic preference to refer to `player_turn` and `computer_turn` separately, instead of working with just one `True`/`False` state - even if the outcome is the same.

Comment: You could also do enum style, so you would write `if turn is Turn.PLAYER:` etc., see https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `random.sample` instead of `random.choice`. Since it picks values without replacement, the second element  is necessarily whichever value wasn't chosen first.

```
player_turn, computer_turn = random.sample([True, False], 2)
```

Or, use an assignment expression (Python 3.8 or later) so that you can negate whichever value is return by `random.choice`:

```
player_turn, computer_turn = (c := random.choice([True, False]), not c)
```

In practice, though, don't maintain two variables whose values have to be kept in sync. One variable indicating *whose* turn it is suffices.

Comment: I like your solution with `random.sample([True, False], 2)` a lot! This was exactly what I had in mind. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Nice one! Great inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must:

```
x, y = [i[1] if i[0]==0 else not i[1] for i in enumerate([random.choice([True, False])]*2)]
```

I guess you get the idea that the two lines are actually not that bad.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That did the trick. I do, however, see your point in keeping my two lines of code :)

Comment: Just because this is a ... subpar one-liner doesn't mean there is no good one-liner.